# Server unable to sort integer array and send to client

Tags: python, arrays, sockets

I'm trying to send random size int array from multiple-clients to server which will keep adding the newly received int array to a global array and return accumulated sorted array to client. My client code is able to send and receive int array to/from server. But server is not able to read the int array and sort and send back to client (My server can just read and send back original int array to client, but it's not what I want).

In my server code, commented part is not working. I am very new in python and socket programming.

Client.py

```
# Import socket module
import socket, pickle
import random


def Main():
    # local host IP '127.0.0.1'
    host = '127.0.0.1'

    # Define the port on which you want to connect
    port = 12345

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # connect to server on local computer
    s.connect((host, port))


    while True:

        # Generate Random array to be sent to server
        arr = []
        # Generate random size between 10 and 20
        # random_size = random.randint(10, 20)
        random_size = random.randint(1, 3)

        for i in range(0, random_size):
            arr.append(random.randint(0, 10))
        print('Array = ' + str(arr))

        # Serialise the array to byte stream before sending to server
        data_stream = pickle.dumps(arr)

        #Array byte stream sent to server
        s.send(data_stream)

        # messaga received from server
        data = s.recv(1024)
        #deserialise the byte stream into array after receiving from server
        data_arr = pickle.loads(data)

        # print the received message
        #print('Received', repr(data_arr))
        print('Received from Server: ', data_arr)

        # ask the client whether he wants to continue
        ans = input('\nDo you want to continue(y/n) :')
        if ans == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break
    # close the connection
    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Server.py

```
# import socket programming library
import socket, pickle

# import thread module
from _thread import *
import threading
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
import bisect

#Container to store accumulated int array from multiple clients
sl = SortedList()

# To protect
print_lock = threading.Lock()


# thread fuction
def threaded(c):
    while True:

        # data received from client
        data = c.recv(1024)
        # Data from client can't be printed =============== why?
        print(data)
        if not data:
            print('No data received from client - Bye')

            # lock released on exit
            print_lock.release()
            break

        c.send(data)  # ===> It works but I want to add received int array into global sl before sending back to client

        '''        
        ////////////////////// Code in this comment section is not working //////////////////
        #Deserialise Byte stream array from client into array list
        data_arr = pickle.loads(data)

        #Add received int array from client to global sortedList sl in sorted order
        for i in data_arr:
            bisect.insort(sl, i)
            sl.add(i)
        print(sl)

        #Serialise sorted sl into Byte stream before sending to client
        data_stream = pickle.dumps(sl)

        # send back sorted integer list to client
        c.send(data_stream)
        '''

    # connection will never be closed, server will run always
    #c.close()


def Main():
    host = ""

    # We can use a port on our specific computer
    # But in this case it is 12345 (it can be anything)
    port = 12345
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    print("socket binded to post", port)

    # put the socket into listening mode
    s.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening")

    # a forever loop until client wants to exit
    while True:
        # establish connection with client
        c, addr = s.accept()

        # lock acquired by client
        print_lock.acquire()
        print('Connected to :', addr[0], ':', addr[1])

        # Start a new thread and return its identifier
        start_new_thread(threaded, (c,))
    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: do you get any error when you run server in terminal/console/cmd.exe ?

Comment: No, I do not get any error when I run server from PyCharm

Comment: When I run Server in terminal/Console then I get error `NotImplementedError: use ``sl.add(value)`` instead`> Run it directly in terminal, not in PyCharm.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Make a reproducible example with expected vs. actual output, and the full traceback of any error messages.  Read [mcve].  Also sockets are not message-based.  `recv(1024)` can receive 0 (socket closed) or 1-1024 bytes.  These could be a partial amount of a previous send, or even parts of two different sends.  All you know is that you get the *bytes* in the same order sent.  *You* have to design a protocol to make sure you have a complete message.  Delimit messages with a special byte or sequence, send the size of the message first, etc.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Got the idea, but for small integers array like mine, it should work I believe. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1):

I run it in terminal and I see error

```
NotImplementedError: use ``sl.add(value)`` instead
```

but it seems to be incomplete message.

After removing

```
bisect.insort(sl, i)
```

it starts working.

Probably there was: ``` use ``sl.add(value)`` instead of ``bisect.insort(sl, i)`` ```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working, I forgot to remove bisect.insort() which I tried for normal List. 
Any idea which one will be more efficient between  List with bisect.insort(list, i) and SortedList.add(i) ?

Comment: I don't know which one is more efficient. I see both first time. You could run both with a lot of random data and check time.